# blank screen after uploading files

Tags: php

I have created a new website in my local PC and it's working fine.

now i  have uploaded  the files to my server. when i run it i  have got a white blank screen (no source behind it).

in my main file - index.php, i have 2 rows that if i remove them the header of the website appear. but i do need them -

```
require_once "func/global.func.php";
require_once "func/users.func.php";
```

those files contain only functions

What is that and how can i fix it?

Comment: look in your `error_log` to see what caused a fatal error giving you the white screen

Comment: Do you need to comment out both files? Have you tried one or the other. This usually occurs due to a syntax error or something. What that something is can be seen if you enable error reporting... Read the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Also versions of php ( which sounds to be different ) between your local and live server could be a possible cause...